# Pandas 'Timestamp' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe that I'm trying to run two different apply operations to:

```
last_consumption_of_year_index = df.loc[(df['date'].dt.month == 12) &
                                  (df['date'].dt.day == 31) &
                                  (df['date'].dt.hour == 23) &
                                  (df['date'].dt.minute == 30)].index[0]


df.loc[:last_consumption_of_year_index]['date'] = df.loc[:last_consumption_of_year_index]['date'].apply(lambda x: x['date'].replace(year=current_year-1))
df.loc[last_consumption_of_year_index+1:]['date'] = df.loc[last_consumption_of_year_index+1:]['date'].apply(lambda x: x['date'].replace(year=current_year))
```

What I want to do is replace the year of the timestamp with `current_year-1` for everything before `last_consumption_of_year_index`, and with `current_year` for everything after.

But I'm getting the error:

`TypeError: 'Timestamp' object is not subscriptable`

Inside in the lambdas. How should I be accessing the date objects?

Additionally, if this isn't the best way to do this, could someone suggest a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe one error might be in your lambda function and the presence of ['date'] in there. Try to replace `lambda x: x['date'].replace(year=current_year-1)` by `lambda x: x.replace(year=current_year-1)` as your method `apply()` is on a Serie and not a Dataframe.

Same with `lambda x: x['date'].replace(year=current_year)` by `lambda x: x.replace(year=current_year)`

Comment: it happens :) for another way, you can try something like: `df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(year=current_year-1)) if cond else x.replace(year=current_year))` where `cond` is your condition on the index of x or something like this. Beside it is with 1 line only (instead of 2) I'm not sure it's faster.

Comment: It's a nice idea, except I can't get the index of a row from the `x['date']` cell can I?

Comment: there are several options, but mainly it implies your x must be unique, such as: `pd.Index(df['date']).get_loc(x) < last_consumption_of_year_index` or `df['date'][df['date'] == x].index[0] < last_consumption_of_year_index` or `(df['date'] == x).idxmax() < last_consumption_of_year_index`. But I'm really not sure of the efficiency of the approach

Comment: another question is what is the definition of `last_consumption_of_year_index`?

Comment: All of those require additional calls to searches which would add some additional performance overhead which would ideally be avoided. I'll add `last_consumption_of_year_index` to the code.

Comment: I agree, then with the definition of `last_consumption_of_year_index` you could do something like: `import datetime` then create your `lim_date = datetime.datetime(current_year, 12, 31, 23, 30)` or something like this and then do a comparison in `lambda x: x.replace(year=current_year-1) if x < lim_date else x.replace(year=current_year))`

Comment: or another idea (sorry I find it really interesting so I do some tries myself) could be: `df['date'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['date'].replace(year=current_year-1)  if x.name <last_consumption_of_year_index else x['date'].replace(year=current_year), axis=1)` as apply is used on the dataframe and not the serie, x contains the row name (number) of x

Comment: Those are both great ideas! I actually tried the second one myself, but had issues with how the data was returned, and gave up trying to coerce everything to work. I'll try your first idea, it's pretty elegant, can't believe I missed it!

Comment: Your idea to create the datetime object (although I used: `last_consumption_of_year = df.loc[(df['date'].dt.month == 12) & (df['date'].dt.day == 31) & (df['date'].dt.hour == 23) (df['date'].dt.minute == 30)]['date'].iloc[0]`), but the idea was excellent!